# GUIDED to LOITER Mode

Tags: dronekit-python, dronekit

I'm trying to change the guided mode to loiter when vehicle reaches a point.
but as soon as mode changes , the altitude is becoming zero - vehicle crashes in 
simulator.

Do i have specify any altitude before changing to loiter mode ?

```
#change the mode to loiter and wait for 10 seconds
vehicle.mode = VehicleMode("LOITER")
while not vehicle.mode.name == "LOITER":
    print "Waiting for vehicle to change to LOITER Mode"
    sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others who are facing the same issue.
assiging 1500 to throttle (after takeoff ?) will solve the issue.

```
armAndTakeOff()
#set the channel overrides which avoids crashing when mode changed to loiter
print "setting throttle channel to 1500 via channel overrides"
vehicle.channels.overrides['3'] = 1500
```

I dont know is this proper way or not, since [dronekit doc](http://python.dronekit.io/examples/channel_overrides.html)  highly dis-commended using rc overrides